# Java Regex replace all between two tags, non XML

Tags: java, regex, replace

I've been looking all night but none of the other answers satify my needs. They don't even run http://regexr.com/ . What i'm looking is to replace all between `<whatever> replace this stuff </whatever>`

```
public void updateValue(String tag, String value) {
    content = content.replaceAll("<"+tag+">(.?+)</"+tag+">", value);
}

public void updateValue(String tag, int value) {
    content = content.replaceAll("<"+tag+">(.?+)</"+tag+">", value+"");
}

public void updateValue(String tag, File value) {
    content = content.replaceAll("(&<"+tag+">=)[^&]*(&</"+tag+">=)", value.getPath());      
}
```

None of them work at all.

**EDIT**

Current approach, tags are beign removed along with it's content by regex.

```
private void replaceValue(String tag, String value) {
    content = content.replaceAll("<"+tag+">(.*?)<\\/"+tag+">", "<"+tag+">"+value+"</"+tag+">");
}
```

Comment: How don't they satisfy your needs? `.?+` is incorrect syntax as that site tells you. What are your needs anyway?

Comment: what is the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It not work because the pattern you are using `(.?+)` is a little weird, it means match any character `.` optional `?` one or more time `+` check [your regex here](https://regex101.com/r/N6isbA/1), to solve your problem you have to make some changes you can use:

```
content = content.replaceAll("<"+tag+">(.+?)<\\/"+tag+">", value);
//--------------------------------------^^^---^^
```

So you have to use `(.+?)`, `(.?+)`, and you have to espace the `/` with `\/`.

check the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N6isbA/2)

---

**Edit**

In the second case you have to use patterns with groups, so you have to match the first tag name then the value between the tags then the closed tag, you can use this :

```
private static void replaceValue(String tag, String value) {
    String regex = "<(.*?)>(.*?)</(.*?)>";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);

    if (matcher.find()) {                                                
        content = content.replaceAll(matcher.group(1), tag)
                .replaceAll(matcher.group(2), value)
                .replaceAll(matcher.group(3), tag);
    }
    System.out.println(content);
}
```

In case of

```
String content = "<MySQL.port>3306</MySQL.port>";
```

and tag = "tag_name", value = "XXXX", the reslt is :

```
<tag_name>XXXX</tag_name>
```

Comment: It doesn't work with empty content between tags, and its removing tags aswell. (i can add'em manually if necessary). EDIT replacing + by * solved the empty case, but tags are still beign removed.

Comment: @WesosdeQueso what should the output look like?

Comment: <MySQL.port>3306</MySQL.port> to <MySQL.port>XXXX</MySQL.port>, for example. It's working but i have to rewrite both <MySQL.port>and </MySQL.port> tags. It's doing : <MySQL.port>3306</MySQL.port> to XXXX

Comment: so `<MySQL.port>` can be any thing else or not?

Comment: Yes, it should work any tag the method recives. See my edit.

Comment: check my edit @WesosdeQueso hope this can help you :)

Comment: I think i'm gonna stick with the current one i have. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
content = content.replaceAll("<tag>(.*?)</tag>", value);
```

**Edited** answer for accepting tag from parameter:

```
content = content.replaceAll("<"+tag"+">(.*?)</"+tag+">", value);
```

Comment: This will replace tag name. It's not what OP is looking for.

Comment: check edited ans

Comment: Now it will replace only tags named `tag`. OP wants to have ability to replace content of any tag.

Comment: Accept that tag as some value.